# How to extarct the string words and special characters between curly brackets in php preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have String like this

```
$string ="this is test {username} ,{password@123} and Other {asdfg@#$}"
```

I want this string as array format as follows

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => username
            [1] => password@123
            [2] => asdfg@#$
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$re = "/\{(.*?)\}/";
$str = "this is test {username} ,{password@123} and Other {asdfg@#\$}";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

this gives what you want

Comment: Thanks dude working as what I want

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<={)[^}]+(?=})
```

Try this.This should work.

```
$re = "/(?<={)[^}]+(?=})/mi";
$str = "this is test {username} ,{password@123} and Other {asdfg@#\$}";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```